# Add image to share intent for a specific app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to implement share logic in my application. Intent contains just a basic text, but there are applications that I need to pass additional image. For that reason I am building intent like this:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    type = "image/jpeg"
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, intentText)
    //putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileToShare)
}

val share = Intent.createChooser(intent, null)
share.putExtra(
    Intent.EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS, bundleOf(
        "com.google.android.gm" to bundleOf(
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM to fileToShare
        ),
        "com.whatsapp" to bundleOf(
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM to fileToShare
        ),
    )
)
```

The problem is the apps that need to receive image cant load passed to `fileToShare` image. There are no errors, just a `Toast` in Telegram that says that something like `Bad file format`. In the same time if i just pass exactly same image not in `createChooser` but in regular intent construction (take a look at the commented line) all works just fine.

Comment: You are not using EXTRA_STREAM in original intent. Why? Moreover you are not showing the value of fileToShare. You can put all in both intents. What is the problem? I'm confused.

Comment: Instagram, for example, dosent accept text with images, it only accepts EXTRA_STREAM. So I don't want to share image with text in instagram. Telegram on the other hand accepts both, but in cases when we provided image it doesn't preload image from URL that we put in EXTRA_TEXT. Whats app has no url-image preload, so i need to pass there image in intent